# How to get parent folder of a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm currently writing a script (for the first time) in powershell that gets called by tfs while building. What I have are the environment variable provided to me such as:

```
$Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY
```

What I need is to get the parent to this directory. How do I do this?

**Update**: Really, I'm just trying to do a Copy-Item to the parent of the parent of $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking too hard.

```
cp $yourFile $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY\..\..
```

Happy scripting!

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a thing as happy scripting. I'm so used to object oriented development, that scripting has left me feeling like I'm just learning how to code!

Answer (score 2):

For a string containing the parent's parent, try this:

(get-item $Env).parent.parent.fullname

Answer (score 1):

From inside the .ps1 script you can use the MyInvocation variable and split path to the parent.  (assuming your .ps1 is in the TF_BUILD_FOLDER already)

```
Split-Path -Parent $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

or this might work.

```
Split-Path -Parent $Env:TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I was wondering if there was a possibility of which I can use ".." to do this instead of using a cmd-let